# IONIC 4 + Angular7: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ionic4, rxjs6

I want to assign the result of creating SQLite database to variable database of type SQLiteObject for this reason I have to do this in "then" block but it shows

> error ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined.

I have tried most of the articles about this error "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"
but none of them is my answer

```
constructor(public http: Http,
    private sqlitePorter: SQLitePorter,
    private storage: Storage,
    private sqlite: SQLite,
    private plateform: Platform) {
    this.databaseReady = new BehaviorSubject(false);
    this.plateform.ready().then(() => {
      this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'developers.db',
        location: 'default',
        })
        .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        this.database = db;
        this.storage.get('database_filled').then(val => {
          if (val) {
            this.databaseReady.next(true);
          } else {
            this.fillDatabase();
          }
        })
      })
    })
  }
```

[image: This is the actual code]

[image: this is the error]

Comment: Which line throws this error?

Comment: `this.plateform`

Comment: `console.log(this.plateform.ready())` must be `undefined`

Comment: line 27 raise the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to return a promise from the first `then`. As you are not returning anything from the first `then` it will return `undefined`. Try something like this.

```
this.plateform.ready().then(() => {
      return this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'developers.db',
        location: 'default',
        })
        .then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
        this.database = db;
        this.storage.get('database_filled').then(val => {
          if (val) {
            this.databaseReady.next(true);
          } else {
            this.fillDatabase();
          }
        })
      })
    })
```